# Using GA Bigquery Export Schema Variables in Google Tag Manger

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-tag-manager

Is there a simple way of accessing the analytics session variables in google tag manager?

I am using BigQuery to connect multiple data bases. One main challenge is to connect a GA session with a certain tag fired within that same session (more specifically, a Double-click Tag).

I have a variable (user id) that can be used to connect my GA sessions with that tag. But to get the specific session where that tag was fired I have to do a lot of workaround with timestamps.

It would be much easier to fire a Session Id (visit Id and Google client Id) inside my Double-click Tag. This way the problem would be later solved with a simple JOIN statement in BigQuery. But I don't know how to define those variables within Google tag Manager. There must be a simple way?

Comment: There are no Google Analytics session identifiers in the client side code (since Universal Analytics was introduced in 2012 sessions are calculated on the GA server). For a practical workaround see Xtothels answer - a session scoped custom dimension will by definition have only one value per session and can thus serve as a surrogate session identifier (and will also be exported to BQ).

Comment: Double-click I'm guessing you mean dfp(for publishers) and that you're trying to simulate a Dmp using BQ<>GTM. that sounds good until you reach the limits in dfp. Just keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try defining a custom JS variable and generate a session ID, something like this:

```
function() {
  var SID = sessionStorage.getItem('mySID');
  if(SID == null){
    sessionStorage.setItem('mySID',Date.now()+"-"+Math.random());
  }
  return SID;
}
```

Then store this in a session scoped custom dimension.

Comment: That would be a nice solution, but I guess that it would only work for browser sessions, and not for distinct GA sessions inside that same browser session?

Comment: My solution so far is using a common variable (in this case GA ID) and then use Tag Firing Timestamps to match with each GA Session 30 min windows.

Comment: The sessionStorage data should “last” shorter than a GA session, since the custom dimension in GA is set as a session scoped CD, it should match GA’s definition of a session. Alternatively, you can generate a new id every time and because it is a session scoped CD, it will apply to the whole GA session.

Comment: Also note, a GA session is not strictly 30mins. The default is that the session ends after 30mins of inactivity. This doesn’t mean sessions are all 30mins long. Example, if user visits page at 0mins, sends at hit at 29mins, then sends another hit at 58mins, at that point in time the session is still the same session at 58mins long.

Comment: And while we are at it, the session also ends at midnight (in the timezone of your GA settings), after 500 hits or (by definition) when the channel attribution changes.